# Scalacheck - Add parameters to commands

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

In the [Scalacheck documentation](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md#stateful-testing) for stateful testing an ATM maschine is mentioned as a use case. For it to work, the commands need parameters, for example the PIN or the withdrawal amount. In the given example the methods in the class `Counter` don't have parameters.

Now my question is how I could test a method like this in scalachecks stateful testing:

```
class Counter {
    private var n = 0
    def inc(i: Int) = n += i
    ...
}
```

The `run` and `nextState` methods of a command don't offer a parameter. Adding a `Random.nextInt` wouldn't work, because in `run` and `nextState` the value would differ and the test fails:

```
case object Inc extends UnitCommand {
    def run(sut: Sut): Unit = sut.inc(Random.nextInt)

    def nextState(state: State): State = state + Random.nextInt
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to pass a parameter to the `Sut`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may notice from how `genCommand`, ScalaCheck `Commands` actually does something like a Cartesian product between initial states generated by `genInitialState` and series of commands generated by `genCommand`. So if some of your commands actually need a parameter, you need to convert them into classes from objects and provide a `Gen` for them. So modifying the example from the docs you will need something like this:

```
/** A generator that, given the current abstract state, should produce
  * a suitable Command instance. */
def genCommand(state: State): Gen[Command] = {
  val incGen = for (v <- arbitrary[Int]) yield Inc(v)
  val decGen = for (v <- arbitrary[Int]) yield Dec(v)
  Gen.oneOf(incGen, decGen, Gen.oneOf(Get, Reset))
}

// A UnitCommand is a command that doesn't produce a result
case class Inc(dif: Int) extends UnitCommand {
  def run(sut: Sut): Unit = sut.inc(dif)

  def nextState(state: State): State = state + dif

  // This command has no preconditions
  def preCondition(state: State): Boolean = true

  // This command should always succeed (never throw an exception)
  def postCondition(state: State, success: Boolean): Prop = success
}

case class Dec(dif: Int) extends UnitCommand {
  def run(sut: Sut): Unit = sut.dec(dif)

  def nextState(state: State): State = state - dif

  def preCondition(state: State): Boolean = true

  def postCondition(state: State, success: Boolean): Prop = success
}
```

Note that if your parameters are just constants rather than variables (as is in the case of PIN-code), you should either hard-code them in the commands or make the whole specification class rather than object and pass those parameters from the outside.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the solution I was looking for!